# Self loop in ln latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=2pt,fill,outer sep=0,circle}}

\begin{document}


 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.60,
       thick,
       acteur/.style={
         circle,
         fill=black,
         thick,
         inner sep=1.2pt,
         minimum size=0.01cm
       }
     ] 
   % \tikzstyle{every loop}=[]
           
           
          
           
           \node (a1) at (0,0) [acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{$1$}]{};
           \node (a2) at (1.5,0)[acteur,label=left:\scriptsize{$2$}]{}; 
           \node (a3) at (0,-1.5) [acteur,label=above left:\scriptsize{$3$}]{}; 
           \node (a4) at (1.5,-1.5) [acteur,label=above right:\scriptsize{$4$}]{}; 
          
          
           \draw  (a1) -- (a2); 
           \draw  (a2) -- (a4); 
           \draw  (a3) -- (a4);
           \draw  (a1) -- (a3);
           \draw  (a2) -- (a3);
          
           
        \draw  (a1) -- (a1);
        
        
%\node at (2.25,-1) {\textit{$U^{+}$}};
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Here I am trying to draw a self loop at vertex 1 and 2. How to draw it? Please help.

[image]

I need this type of loop without arrow

Comment: Make sure the actual question is outside the code block otherwise people won't be able to see it...

Comment: how we can do it outside the code block?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321312/110998

Comment: But I have different one

Comment: please help....

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with the image you used to illustrate it.

Comment: And also, not related but you already asked a few question and never accepted one of the answers that members have posted. You may want to do that, as a gesture of good behaviour.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks.